# Jquery submit form

Tags: jquery, forms, submit

How can I submit a specific form using the follow code (example the id of my form is #form1).

```
$(".nextbutton").click(function() { submit; });
```

Answer (score 60):

Try this
lets say your form id is formID

```
$(".nextbutton").click(function() { $("form#formID").submit(); });
```

Comment: Isn't "form#formID" a bit redundant? "#formID" would be sufficient, right?

Comment: Yes, only the ID would suffice. But prepending it with the tagname speeds up the search for the item. If you add it, only <form> element will be evaluated until the correct ID is found. Granted, most webpages don't have that much HTML to actually have a delay in searching, but it still is better practice to prepend the tagname if you know it.

Comment: according to the documentation here http://api.jquery.com/submit/
this will add a submit listener on the form, not actually submit it.
the submit function is not the same on a jQuery object and on a DOM element.

Comment: This definitely submits the form.... in this case, with id 'formID'

Comment: @challet the documentation you link to does list a no-argument form of `submit` that is a shortcut for `.trigger('submit')` and submits the form.

Comment: you're right, blame on me :)

Comment: @Flater : no, searching for an ID uses the native getElementById which is as fast as an hashtable allows it to be. Prepending a tag name to an ID will only add an useless filtering process.

Answer (score 8):

You can try like:

```
   $("#myformid").submit(function(){
        //perform anythng
   });
```

Or even you can try like

```
$(".nextbutton").click(function() { 
    $('#form1').submit();
});
```

Comment: according to http://api.jquery.com/submit/ , this will only add an event listener

Comment: @challet: According to an example lower down in the page you linked to, it does submit the form.

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need to do it all in jQuery to do that smoothly. Do it like this:

```
$(".nextbutton").click(function() { 
   document.forms["form1"].submit();
});
```

Comment: funny, cause you use jquery in your answer that says you don't need jquery?

Comment: I guess he meant the part of submitting the form :)

Comment: .submit() doesnt work for me. says property submit is not a function

Comment: doesn't work. says "submit is not a function"

Comment: This is true but if you've got jQuery available as a tool for selecting DOM elements, you might as well be consistent. Otherwise you're introducing redundancy.

Comment: why use jQuery in your answer if you say it isn't needed?

Comment: I ment the part that submits the form.

Answer (score 2):

Since a *jQuery* object inherits from an array, and this array contains the selected DOM elements.
Saying you're using an id and so the element should be unique within the DOM, you could perform a direct call to *submit* by doing :

```
$(".nextbutton").click(function() { 
  $("#formID")[0].submit();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have only 1 form in you page, use this. You do not need to know id or name of the form. I just used this code - working:

```
document.forms[0].submit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following jquery to submit a selectbox with out a submit button. Use "change" instead of click as shown above.

```
$("selectbox").change(function() { 
   document.forms["form"].submit();
});
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$('#form1').submit();
```

or

```
document.form1.submit();
```