# Auto submit MVC form with jQuery when drop downs change not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I wonder if someone can shed some light why my form would not submit with the following script.  I need the from to submit as soon as the drop-down changed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("select").change(function () {
        $("#sform").submit(); // Trigger form load
        //alert('form to reload!');
    });

});
```

And the form something like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ServiceNumbers", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "sform" }))
{
  <div> Companies:
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CompanyID, Model.CompaniesList, "")
  </div>
}
```

The commented out alert triggers when uncommented, the form itself does not submit.  I am obviously doing something wrong, or maybe this cannot work for some reason?  Related posts have not shed any light so far, still searching.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

I tried most of the items in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752134/jquery-submit-form) post.  None seems to work.

I can make the whole form disappear with:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("select").change(function () {
        //$("form#sform").submit(); // Trigger form load
        //alert('form to reload! len=' + $("#sform").length);
        //document.forms["sform"].submit();
        //document.sform.submit();
        $("form#sform").html("");
    });
```

But submit - no way.  The only conclusion I can get to is that it has something to do with the MVC *modernizr-1.7.min.js* script.

Comment: post the generated html instead of ASP server-side.

Comment: Looks right. Any chance your not passing client side validation, returning false on the form submit?

Answer (score 0):

Can you alert `$("#sform").length` and see? I suspect the form id is not the same when it is rendered on the page.

Comment: Thanks for response, tried everything I can think of, given up.