# How to put into "f.submit" helper some HTML code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, helper

If I need to add something into **link_to** helper, there's a way to do that this way:

```
= link_to path do
 inner content
```

But this approach doesn't work for **f.submit** helper. I would need to add there some HTML entities. How to do that?

Comment: What kind of inner content would you want to add? Can't this be appended / prepended to the ``f.submit`` call?

Comment: It's "just" an icon from the **font awesome** library.

Comment: @user984621: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2920093/125816

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't. `<input type="submit" />` is a button, as specified here: http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input/submit. HTML buttons can't display arbitrary content.

Instead you could build a link tag (or whatever tag you want) and then attach a click handler to it which will submit the form with javascript.

Related link: [Submit a form with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3752144/125816).