# JQuery to Submit a Form - Spot the Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752134/jquery-submit-form) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200266/submit-a-form-using-jquery) but can't get my form to submit. (noob to Jquery...)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Book Notes Application - Subjects</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#subject_id').change(function(){
                var subject_id = $(this).val();
                //alert(subject_id)
                //document.forms["choose_subject"].submit();
                $('#choose_subject').submit();
                //$('form#choose_subject').submit();
                //$('form#choose_subject')[0].submit();
                //alert(subject_id);
                //document.getElementById("choose_subject").submit();
            })
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- CHOOSE SUBJECT -->
    <FORM action="/books" id="choose_subject" name="choose_subject" method="POST">
        Choose a Subject:
        <select name="subject_id" id="subject_id">
                <option value="1">a</option>
                <option value="2">a2</option>
        </select><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Choose Subject"/>
        <BR />
    </FORM>
    <!-- CREATE SUBJECT -->
    <FORM action="/subjects" id="create_subject" method="POST">

        <BR /><BR />
        Create a new Subject
        <input type="text" name="subject_name" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create Subject" />
    </FORM>
<body>
</html>
```

I've tried each of these methods:

```
1) document.forms["choose_subject"].submit();
2) $('#choose_subject').submit();
3) $('#choose_subject')[0].submit();
4) $('form#choose_subject').submit();
5) $('form#choose_subject')[0].submit();
6) document.getElementById("choose_subject").submit();
```

The first and last result in a "TypeError: document.forms.choose_subject.submit is not a function.

The second and fourth don't have an error but they also doesn't do anything.

The third and fifth error out with a "TypeError: $(...)[0].submit is not a function"

If I remove the second form these results hold true.

Clicking the submit button works as expected.

Comment: Did you specify what data type you form is submitting?

Comment: Can you post the rendered HTML, not whatever that is. Something else is interfering, because as you can see, a basic jsFiddle using your code works: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/66f7Y/. Although it will still submit even without the jQuery.

Comment: @j08691 Edited with the rendered HTML (it was python's Bottle btw)

Comment: @Mr.Student Pardon me; what do you mean?

Comment: Do you have any other JavaScript running on your page? I don't see why you'd need JS to submit the form since the submit button will do it by default.

Comment: @j08691 the effort involved in clicking a submit button is strenuous.

Comment: try setting enctype="multipart/form-data" as a form attribute.

Comment: Also, take out <br />

Comment: @Mr.Student - Both totally unnecessary.

Comment: You also have two <html> tags at the top

Comment: @Mr.Student the enctype tag didnt work :(. The double <html> was a copy and paste error; I've edited it out now.

Comment: Did you include jQuery?

Comment: @j08691 Nope there is no other JS.

Comment: @Mr.Student From what I understand, the `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` includes the Jquery. The alert function that I commented out successfully alerts the subject_id when the select box is changed.

Comment: How is $().change() being triggered?

Comment: @Mr.Student The select box changing triggers it. If I uncomment the alert it successfully alerts the subject_id when the select box is changed.

Comment: Have you opened up a js console to check if the form is not submitting. How do you know it's not working?

Comment: @Mr.Student Yes I have a console up. Its not working because I'm not being directed to the next page, which occurs when I click on the submit button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your the name of your input element:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Choose Subject"/>
```

to something other than "submit". As the [.submit() docs state](https://api.jquery.com/submit/):

> Forms and their child elements should not use input names or ids that
>   conflict with properties of a form, such as submit, length, or method.
>   Name conflicts can cause confusing failures.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/66f7Y/1/)**

Comment: **+1** Excellent catch!

Comment: @druciferre - Thanks. I'd file this under the "confusing failures" that the docs refer to ;)